# Display JSON list from dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic-forms

Alright, so I have not worked with JSON before. So far I am able to display the last information entered, but I need to display each input that is entered. How can I loop through my current function to do this? Would I need to do a for loop? If so, could I get some tips on how that would look? Any help would be great!

**EDIT:** The code is long so I inserted my codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/cfay1810/pen/RxVByz)

```js
  

  var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "form-handler";
    form.onsubmit = submitForm;

    var add = document.getElementsByClassName("add");
    add[0].onclick = houseList;
    var lastId = 0;

    var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
    age.type = "number";
    age.required = true;
    age.min = "0";
    age.max = "120";

    var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
    dropDown.type = "option";
    dropDown.required = true;

    var smoker = document.getElementsByName("smoker")[0];

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
    newDiv.appendChild(ul);
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("House Member List"));
    ul.appendChild(h2);

    function houseList() {
      if (age == null || age.value === "") {
        alert("Age must be filled out");
        return false;
      } else if (age.value == age.max) {
        alert("Age must be 120 years old or less!");
        return false;
      } else if (dropDown.value == "") {
        alert("Please choose a relationship");
        return false;
      } else {
        var li = document.createElement("li");

        if (smoker.checked) {
          li.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
              dropDown.value + " " + age.value + ", Smoker " + " "
            )
          );
        } else {
          li.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
              dropDown.value + " " + age.value + ", Non-Smoker " + " "
            )
          );
        }

        li.setAttribute("id", "item" + lastId);
        ul.appendChild(li);

        var remove = document.createElement("button");
        remove.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));
        remove.onclick = removeItem;
        remove.setAttribute("onclick", 'removeItem("' + "item" + lastId + '")');

        li.appendChild(remove);
        lastId += 1;
        ul.appendChild(li);

        return false;
      }
    }

    function removeItem(itemid) {
      var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
      item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    }

// THE CODE IN QUESTION
      function submitForm() {
      var display = document.getElementsByClassName("debug")[0];
      var members = new Object();
      members.Member = dropDown.value;
      members.Age = age.value;
      members.Smoker = smoker.checked;
      var jsonText = JSON.stringify(members);
      display.textContent = jsonText;
      console.log(jsonText);
      alert("Form has been submitted!");
      return false;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Household builder</title>
      <style>
        .debug {
          font-family: monospace;
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 10px;
          display: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Household builder</h1>
      <div class="builder">
        <ol class="household"></ol>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Age
                            <input type="text" name="age">
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Relationship
                            <select name="rel">
                                <option value="">---</option>
                                <option value="self">Self</option>
                                <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                                <option value="child">Child</option>
                                <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                                <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                                <option value="other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Smoker?
                            <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="add">add</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <pre class="debug"></pre>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: fix the link, it is broken...

Comment: My bad, I edited the link.

Comment: not  really clear the problem.. your Pen looks working. What is missing?

Comment: Well I need to display the JSON for each input. So if you enter more than one member, it should display them in the JSON format. However, right now, if you enter more than one member it only lists the last member. So I was wondering if there is a loop I could use to grab each input and display it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: this code needs to be refactored, it's using Html tags instead of your own objects